# Problem restoring Wagtail CMS media folder when copying from staging to prod environment

Tags: nginx, amazon-ecs, wagtail

I'm having problems restoring the images for my Wagtail website contained in a media folder. I have two Wagail CMS sites, one development/staging environment and another production environment. The sites are running on AWS inside of Docker containers, and the database is a PostgreSQL database inside RDS. The source code for the site is in GitHub. When I commit a code change, it triggers a new build using AWS' CodeBuild; this creates a new container. I copy over the media folder containing the current images, change the owner/group for the folder, and set the folder's permissions. When I go to the site, the images are missing although I copied over the media folder into the new container instance. The only solution I've found is to manually re-add the images. I wonder if my issue is connected to not executing the "python manage.py collectstatic" command when I create a new container instance. Technically, the media folder contains static files, but I've held off executing the command until I full understand what it does.

Any ideas on how to resolve the images issue?

Answer (score 3):

Images don't only exist as file in the media folder but also in the database through the Image model. Simply having them in the folder isn't enough.

There are currently no mechanism to transfer data between Wagtail instances. There is an [RFC](https://github.com/wagtail/rfcs/pull/42) and [the begining of an implementation](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-transfer) but nothing production ready yet.